# ServicePartitionResolver.ResolveAsync hang on forever

Tags: c#, azure, service-fabric-stateless

When I use the below code, the method ResolveAsync hang on forever.

How can I resolve the partition ?

Changing the `ServicePartitionKey.Singleton` to `new ServicePartitionKey()` does not solve the issue.

```
internal sealed class CryptoPriceService : StatelessService
{
[...]
  protected override Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           return Task.Run(() =>
           {
               var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
               var partition = resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/CryptoPriceWebSite/OtherService"),
                   ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                   cancellationToken).Result; // Hang on forever
               var addressJson = JObject.Parse(partition.GetEndpoint().Address);
               var address = addressJson["Endpoints"][Constantes.BusEndpoint].ToString();

 [...]
               Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
           });
       }
}
```

Comment: Try `await resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/CryptoPriceWebSite/OtherService"),
                   ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                   cancellationToken);`. .Result is blocking.

Comment: I have already tried that one, It does not solve the problem. The issue here is that ResolveAsync method never returns

Answer (score 0):

I know this quite old question, but in order for this method not to hang, you should pass a cancellation token with the desired time out.
For example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/CryptoPriceWebSite/OtherService"),
               ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
               cancellationToken.Token).Result;
```